# launch problem electric arm navigation tutorial

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-electric, arm-navigation, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to run the first electric arm navigation tutorial called 'Planning Description Configuration Wizard'. Once I launch the PR2 example I get the following error:
[planning_description_configuration_wizard-4] process has died [pid 6087, exit code -11].
log files: /home/wouter/.ros/log/a6475bbe-d2f2-11e0-859e-002710aa9e70/planning_description_configuration_wizard-4*.log
waiting...

Running roswtf in a separate terminal gives the following error:

```
ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
 * planning_environment: found flag "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib", but no matching "-L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib"
 * pcl: found flag "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib64", but no matching "-L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib64"
 * pcl_ros: found flag "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib", but no matching "-L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib"
 * robot_self_filter: found flag "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib64", but no matching "-L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib64"
```

As suggested in another question (http://answers.ros.org/question/1212/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-rpath-in-manifestxml) I already tried to remove the -L prefix in the manifest.xml files but that didn't work. Therefore I reinstalled the debian package to make sure that I have the original manifest.xml file.

My OS is Ubuntu 11.04 with ROS Electric installed. Furthermore I have installed the Debian package called 'ros-electric-arm-navigation'.

Does anyone know how I can get the tutorial to work?

Wouter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11059/launch-problem-electric-arm-navigation-tutorial/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2011-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I rolled back my linux installation to 10.04 32 bit and this solved the issue. Apparently the package is neither running properly under 11.04 nor under 10.04 64bit.

---

Originally posted by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) with karma: 130 on 2011-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-18**:
So on mine. Maybe this is not the right answer and the whole question should be marked as unanswered.

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-09-03**:
It does run fine on my installation of Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.